# Stop LifeCam HD-5000 from constantly changing focus

Tags: camera

My LifeCam HD-5000 camera is constanly changing focus, while capturing video. Nothing can stop it.

Is it possible to disable the autofocus feature or to make it more tolerant?

Demonstration: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olxAl12Z1MA

Even it can't be heard, that camera starts to emit clicking sounds just before starting to change focus. Either this is the focus motor, or it is a sign of some damage.

How can I make it stop doing that?

Comment: Is the lens clean? the only behavior I can think of that causes this is dust or grease on the lens. Cleaning it may solve it.

Comment: lens are clean; looks like it is buggie algorithm, which is searching focus once picture changes; would like to know how to overcome it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **Windows 10** see see [ToxaZ's solution above/below](https://superuser.com/a/1419054/254433).

For **Windows < 10**:

This camera has a known issue with autofocus that:

- **Excessive Face Detection**: Constantly looks for a face and tries to focus to it.
- **Too Sensitive**: even a small movement triggers autofocus.
- **Too Slow**: it takes a few seconds to focus.

For me, on **Windows 10 64-bit** the following procedure helped to **disable autofocus completely, also after restart**:

1. **Upgrade Firmware**: Download it from [Microsoft’s official site here](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-ca/d/lifecam-hd-5000).
2. **Install LifeCam Software**: Use the link above to find it.
3. **Disable Autofocus in LifeCam Software Settings**: see the screenshot below for an exact step-by-step instruction.

Now these settings should be used in all applications using the camera, including your video capture app, Skype, etc.

[image: Screenshot showing how to disable autofocus in LifeCam software]

Comment: Sorry can't check if this applicable for me, since camera stopped working long time ago and have another one now :)

Comment: No longer supported since Windows 10 Creators update.

Comment: Given that LifeCam software no longer works in Windows 10, the solution presented by @ToxaZ below (https://superuser.com/a/1419054/1174807) appears to work well.

Answer (score 25):

For Windows 10 v1809, the solution that worked is:

1. Open Camera app (installed by default - can also be installed [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-camera/9wzdncrfjbbg?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab))
2. Select Focus Settings in the top menu
3. There is a half-circle scroll on the right side, with the bottom position being autofocus. To adjust manually, drag it up (autofocus will be turned off in other apps too).

Comment: Worked well. Thanks! Just wanted to note I had to first turn on "Pro Mode" in the settings to get the focus settings to appear.

Comment: I had to enable "Pro mode" before I was offered the option to change the focus from auto to manual. (Windows 10 19041.450)

Answer (score 8):

Disabling the autofocus can be done via the DirectShow API, and luckily someone made a program that just does that: [FocusUF](https://github.com/anotherlab/FocusUF)

> Command line tool for locking the focus of any webcam that supports IAMCameraControl control interface from DirectShowLib
>
> The LifeCam HD-5000 webcam is a decent webcam with an annoying feature. The autofocus keeps shifting the focus around if you move your head slightly. When you are in a video chat with someone, this can get annoying for the other viewers. Your face will shift in and out of focus.

Put a link to it in the startup folder, because in my experience, this setting is not remembered. This also works for my LifeCam HD-6000, which has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

One other note I'd like to add ..

You have to install in compatibility mode for Windows 7 or it gets REALLY messed up.

If you have windows 10 download LifeCam3.60 and the webcam drivers. Lifecam will let you open settings under start menu. Type `lifecam` and you will see Microsoft Lifecam.

When you use compatibility mode it will let you launch it WHILE on webcam...

If you don't for some reason, it will say webcam is in use if you are on webcam in your browser for example, you would have to stop broadcasting there, adjust your settings, then broadcast again.

There was a firmware update not sure if that may have fixed some issues, but I'm sure others exist ...

1. Click Start.
2. In the Start Search box, type "Regedit", and then press ENTER.
3. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\LifeCam.
4. click New, and then click DWORD (32-bit) Value
5. Give the registry entry the name `AutofocusOFF`
6. Right-click the registry entry name, and then click Modify.
7. Type 1, and then click OK.

   ```
   "AutofocusOFF"=dword:00000001
   ```
8. Restart windows

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that I stumble upon in Microsoft forum and work for me (win 10 after Creator update), When there was not feasible way to install the camera software:

I used skype video settings to cancel auto-focus and adjust fixed  focus.