# How to disable autofocus in Zoom Windows?

Tags: windows, webcam, focus

I have a Microdia Sonix 1080p webcam (a Logitech knockoff, pretty much all that was available) and although the picture is quite good when it focuses properly, the autofocus constantly goes back and forth between my face and the background in my office. If I use the Windows Camera app and set the manual focus, that works only within the Camera app, but as soon as I start Zoom for videoconferencing, autofocus takes over and there is no way to set it back to manual focus. Has anyone found a solution to this?

btw, I tried the suggestions found in [Stop LifeCam HD-5000 from constantly changing focus](https://superuser.com/questions/839119/stop-lifecam-hd-5000-from-constantly-changing-focus/1419054) Changing the focus to manual in the Camera app is immediately overridden by Zoom to autofocus every time that a Zoom meeting is started. I've downloaded the FocusUF utility which works like a charm but has to be rerun every time that I start a Zoom meeting: get into the meeting, force the autofocus to focus on my face, then run the utility. It works, but is annoying that it has to be done every time I start a Zoom meeting.